# Calling hist() with group_by in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement `hist()` and using a `group_by` statement. I know this could be done with `geom_histogram` much easier, but at this point `hist()` is prefered.

```
info <- data.frame
data %>% 
  group_by(par1, par2, par3) %>% 
  hist(value,breaks = seq(min(data$value), max(data$value)+5, by = 5), plot = FALSE)
```

So, basically by using `plot = FALSE` the function won't return a plot, but instead, I will get the calculated data. My wish is to save these to info.  But, I don't know how even call `hist()` inside of a `group_by`. I get the following error when I run the code `'x' must be numeric` but if I just run this line:

```
  hist(data$value,breaks = seq(min(data$value), max(data$value)+5, by = 5), plot = FALSE)
```

it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the data and apply `hist` function to each group using `map`.

Using `mtcars` as an example :

```
library(dplyr)

hist_plot <- mtcars %>%
              group_split(cyl) %>%
              purrr::map(~with(.x, hist(mpg,
               breaks = seq(min(mpg), max(mpg)+5, by = 5), plot = FALSE)))
```

This returns output as :

```
hist_plot[[1]]

#$breaks
#[1] 21.4 26.4 31.4 36.4

#$counts
#[1] 6 3 2

#$density
#[1] 0.10909091 0.05454545 0.03636364

#$mids
#[1] 23.9 28.9 33.9

#$xname
#[1] "mpg"

#$equidist
#[1] TRUE

#attr(,"class")
#[1] "histogram"
```

If you want to keep the information in dataframe you can do :

```
hist_plot <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(plot_data = list(with(cur_data(), hist(mpg,
             breaks = seq(min(mpg), max(mpg)+5, by = 5), plot = FALSE))))

#  cyl plot_data 
#  <dbl> <list>    
#1     4 <histogrm>
#2     6 <histogrm>
#3     8 <histogrm>
```